# Set of matrices commutative to the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $U$ is set of all matrices that commute with matrix:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix} $ prove that $U$ is subspace of $\mathbb{M}_{3X3}$ determine if it contains $span(I, A, A^2, ...)$ and then determine dimensions and one basis of given subspaces.

I know that square matrices commute with $I, A, A^2, ...$ but i don't know if there are more matrices that commute with this one, so i don't know how to determine elements of the set $U$, which is subspace of $\mathbb{M}_{3X3}$ as it's    stated, but i don't know how to prove that since i don't know how to determine $U$ which means that i don't know if it contains given span either. Any ideas?

Comment: Not all square matrices commute with $A$. Consider $S=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$ where $SA= \pmatrix{3&0&4\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$ while $AS=\pmatrix{0&0&2\\0&0&0\\0&0&3}$

Comment: @MarkFischler Ok,thank you, i'll keep that in mind, but that fact won't help me to solve this. Do you know something more that could help me solve this particular problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $B=(b_{ij})$ be an arbitrary $3\times 3$-matrix satisfying $AB=BA$. Then this matrix equation is equivalent to $9$ equations in the variables $b_{ij}$, which have a very easy solution:
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & 0 & b_1-b_5 \cr 3(b_1 - b_5 - b_8) &  b_5   & b_8
\cr  3(b_1 - b_5)  &   0   & 3b_1 - 2b_5 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here I rewrote the matrix with the $9$ entries as $b_1,\ldots ,b_9$. This is the general solution. Of course, powers of $A$ commute with $A$ by definition.

Comment: Ok, i see, and it is relatively easy to prove that this is the subspace of $\mathbb{M}_{3X3}$ but how can i determine if it contains $span(I, A, A^2, ...)$?

Comment: @cdummie Is $A^k\cdot A = A\cdot A^k$?  Is then $A^k$ in $U$?  (Remember that $A^k\cdot A = \underbrace{A\cdot A\cdots A}_{k~\text{times}}\cdot A$)

Comment: You can also compute explicitly what $A^k$ is. Note that the Jordan form of $A$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 5\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Obviously $A^k$ is in $U$, but, span is set of all linear combinations of it's elements. How can i know that every linear combination of $I, A, A^2, ...$ is in $U$?

Comment: Because $U$ is a subspace, all linear combinations are again in $U$.

Comment: @cdummie if each individually is in $U$, then any linear combination of them is too... Suppose you have two things you know are in $U$.  If you have $B$ and $C$ which are in $U$, then $(bB+cC)A = bBA+cCA = bAB + cAC = A(bB)+A(cC)=A(bB+cC)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand now. What about the last part of the problem? IT says " then determine dimensions and one basis of given subspaces." why it says "subspaces" when there's only one subspace? How can i find basis of it?

Comment: @cdummie Dietrich already explained what the general form of a matrix which commutes with $A$ is above in this very post.  To have reached that step, solve the equation $AB=BA$ where $B$ is arbitrary, giving nine equations and nine unknowns.  Try rewriting the general form as $b_1\cdot E_1 + b_5\cdot E_2 + b_8\cdot E_3$ where $E_1,E_2,E_3$ act as your basis.